# How to create signed PKCS#7 message with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, pkcs#7, certenroll

I'm trying to create signed PKCS#7 message for PKCS#10 certifacate request on client-side with javascript.

There are good examples on PKCS#10: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/01/28/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-javascript.aspx

But I need to create PKCS#7 and cannot figure out how to do it. There is a lack of examples (actually no at all) on official documentation for CertEnroll: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374850(v=vs.85).aspx

I've ended up with this code:

```js
var XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64REQUESTHEADER = 3;

var XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE = 0;

var _certEnrollClassFactory = new ActiveXObject("X509Enrollment.CX509EnrollmentWebClassFactory");


ComposePKCS10Request: function (containerName, subject)
{
    // PKCS #10 certificate request
    var objRequest = _certEnrollClassFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10");

    var objCSP = objCertEnrollClassFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CCspInformation");
    var objCSPs = objCertEnrollClassFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CCspInformations");

    //  Initialize the csp object using the desired Cryptograhic Service Provider (CSP)
    objCSP.InitializeFromName("Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0");

    //  Add this CSP object to the CSP collection object
    objCSPs.Add(objCSP);

    // asymmetric private key that can be used for encryption, signing, and key agreement.
    var objPrivateKey = _certEnrollClassFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509PrivateKey");

    //  Provide key container name, key length and key spec to the private key object
    objPrivateKey.ContainerName = containerName;
    //objPrivateKey.Length = 1024;
    objPrivateKey.KeySpec = 1; // AT_KEYEXCHANGE = 1

    //  Provide the CSP collection object (in this case containing only 1 CSP object)
    //  to the private key object
    objPrivateKey.CspInformations = objCSPs;

    // Initialize P10 based on private key
    objRequest.InitializeFromPrivateKey(1, objPrivateKey, ""); // context user = 1

    // X.500 distinguished name (DN)
    // The DN consists of a sequence of relative distinguished names (RDNs). Each RDN consists of a set of attributes, 
    // and each attribute consists of an object identifier (OID) and a value. The data type of the value is identified 
    // by the DirectoryString structure.
    var objDn = _certEnrollClassFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX500DistinguishedName");

    // DN related stuff
    objDn.Encode(subject, XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);
    objRequest.Subject = objDn;

    return objRequest;
}

CreatePKCS7: function (containerName, subject)
{
    // PKCS #7 certificate request
    var objPKCS7Request = _certEnrollClassFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs7");

    // initialize PKCS #7 certificate request by PKCS #10 certificate request
    objPKCS7Request.InitializeFromInnerRequest(this.ComposePKCS10Request(containerName, subject));

    var objSignerCert = _certEnrollClassFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CSignerCertificate");
    var verifyType = 4; /* VerifyAllowUI, see typedef enum X509PrivateKeyVerify */
    var encodingType = 0x3; /* see typedef enum EncodingType */

    /**********************************************************************/
    /* I have to provide certificate here??? How can I obtain it from UI? */
    /**********************************************************************/
    var strCertificate = '?????????????????????';

    objSignerCert.Initialize(false, verifyType, encodingType, strCertificate);

    /*****************************************************************************/
    /* Also I'm not shure that SignerCertificate can be accessed via javascript. */
    /*****************************************************************************/
    objPKCS7Request.SignerCertificate = objSignerCert;

    // represents the top level object and enables you to enroll in a certificate hierarchy and install a certificate response
    var objEnroll = _certEnrollClassFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509Enrollment");

    // Enroll
    objEnroll.InitializeFromRequest(objPKCS7Request);

    var pkcs7;

    try
    {
        pkcs7 = objEnroll.CreateRequest(XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64REQUESTHEADER);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        ...
    }

    return pkcs7;
}
```

Is there any way to create PKCS#7 message with javascript?

UPDATE: I've already had PKCS#10 cert request (see the first function in code sample) and need to create PKCS#7 signed message for it. Ok, I paraphrase my question. How to create signed PKCS#7 message with javascript? (Ideally, it should allow to specify proper cert with UI.)

As for javascript I understand that it's not the convenient way, but suitable because I must to deal with it on client-side (in browser). Moreover, cert enroll IX509CertificateRequestPkcs7 interface has methods marked as [WebEnabled], so I believe there must be the way to do what I state.

Comment: You've provided a large block of code. What exactly is wrong with it? Does it compile? Does it produce an error?

Comment: I've put noticeable comments in the code (marked with /******/). In fact, I try to create signed PKCS#7 message and don't know how to provide SignerCert. Do not rule out there may be the different way to achieve this.

Comment: There is no such thing as a PKCS#7 certificate request. You might want to encrypt the PKCS#10 certificate request though (e.g. to keep the information that is to be contained in the certificate confidential). But for that to work you need more than a document that states that it has to be PKCS#7 encoded, you need something that defines the precise PKCS#7 envelope.

Comment: For signing you also need access to the private key, although the private keys are normally linked with the certificate. Providing a pin or password for access ro the key may be tricky too.

Comment: Did you finally figure it out? I'm looking for something similar

Comment: Your question title and question body are misaligned. The title says you are using javascript, but the body implies you're using proprietary COM API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VBScript method** (it will prompt to choose certificate):

```vb
Function SignMessage(Message)
    Dim oUtils
    Set oUtils = CreateObject("CAPICOM.Utilities")
    Dim cpcSigner
    Set cpcSigner = CreateObject("CAPICOM.Signer")
    cpcSigner.Options = 2 'CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_INCLUDE_END_ENTITY_ONLY
    Dim cpcSignedData
    Set cpcSignedData = CreateObject("CAPICOM.SignedData")
    cpcSignedData.Content = oUtils.Base64Decode(Message)
    SignMessage = cpcSignedData.Sign(cpcSigner, False)
End function
```

**Javascript method** (*be carefull due to encoding strings in JS you will get corrupted signature, so I suggest to **use VBScript** for signing data in your client scripts since it interoperable with JS*):

```js
var CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_INCLUDE_END_ENTITY_ONLY = 2;

SignMessage: function (message) {
    var cpcSigner = new ActiveXObject("CAPICOM.Signer");
    cpcSigner.Options = CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_INCLUDE_END_ENTITY_ONLY;

    var cpcSignedData = new ActiveXObject("CAPICOM.SignedData");
    var oUtils = new ActiveXObject("CAPICOM.Utilities");
    cpcSignedData.Content = oUtils.Base64Decode(message);

    return cpcSignedData.Sign(cpcSigner, false);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do PKCS#7 and PKCS#10 in pure JS using Forge (works in browser or node.js):

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#pkcs7

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#pkcs10

Answer (score 1):

PKCS#7 format is defined in [rfc2315](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315) using ASN.1 notation.

#### ASN.1

ASN.1 is a notation for defining data structures. Additionaly, there is also DER - encoding rules that define how ASN.1 notation is encoded as binary data.

#### ASN1.js encoder

So the question boils down to "are there any JS-libraries that implements ASN1?"
There are [some decoding libraries](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=asn1&ref=cmdform&type=Repositories)

But the only encoder is this one: https://github.com/indutny/asn1.js

#### ContentInfo and types

Let's dive deeper. The ASN.1 for PKCS#7 follows:

```
ContentInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  contentType ContentType,
  content
    [0] EXPLICIT ANY DEFINED BY contentType OPTIONAL }

ContentType ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER
```

Here we need to understand what is OBJECT IDENTIFIER. It is a special sequence of numbers that defines some type. Valid object identifiers for PKCS#7 follow:

```
data OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { pkcs-7 1 }
signedData OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { pkcs-7 2 }
envelopedData OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { pkcs-7 3 }
signedAndEnvelopedData OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { pkcs-7 4 }
digestedData OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { pkcs-7 5 }
encryptedData OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { pkcs-7 6 }
```

pkcs-7 is an object identifier for PKCS#7 format.

```
pkcs-7 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=
  { iso(1) member-body(2) US(840) rsadsi(113549)
      pkcs(1) 7 }
```

As you can see, there's `ANY DEFINED BY contentType` modifier for the `content` field. It means that this field can be any of 6 types depending on the value of contentType field.

It seems like you need signed message, so the content type would be "signedData"

#### ContentInfo encoding using JS

How this translates into ASN1.js code? Here you're:

```
var PKCS7_CONTENT_TYPES = {
    "1 2 840 113549 1 7 1": "data",
    "1 2 840 113549 1 7 2": "signedData",
    "1 2 840 113549 1 7 3": "envelopedData",
    "1 2 840 113549 1 7 4": "signedAndEnvelopedData",
    "1 2 840 113549 1 7 5": "digestData",
    "1 2 840 113549 1 7 6": "encryptedData",
};

var ContentInfo = asn1.define('ContentInfo', function() {
    this.seq().obj(
        this.key('contentType').objid(PKCS7_CONTENT_TYPES),
        this.key('content').optional().explicit(0).any()
    );
});
```

So, how to use this ContentInfo?

```
var signedData = ...
   contentInfoEncoded = ContentInfo.encode({
     'contentType': 'signedData',
     'content': signedData
   })
```

#### SignedData

To be continued...

Comment: Does this solution works on browser ? and how can I make it work in a browser

Comment: @ibrahim asn1.js is a node module. It can be compiled to browser javascript using browserify http://browserify.org/

Comment: Very nice answer! I have an XML-digital signature  which i need to be in PKCS#7 format. I would really much appreciate if you could continue the example in order to have the complete ASN.1 blob!